# Error while clustering data with kmeans

Tags: mahout, k-means, cluster-analysis

I'm trying to perform clustering for k means algorithm for the input data shown here:
https://cwiki.apache.org/MAHOUT/clustering-of-synthetic-control-data.html
However when the map reduce job is about to take place i get the error

```
11/10/16 21:05:57 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201110161920_0008_m_000000_0,     Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.math.Vector
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:762)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableName.getClass(WritableName.java:71)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.getValueClass(SequenceFile.java:1613)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.init(SequenceFile.java:1555)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1428)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1417)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1412)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileRecordReader.initialize(SequenceFileRecordReader.java:50)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.initialize(MapTask.java:418)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:620)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:305)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:170)

11/10/16 21:06:03 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201110161920_0008_m_000000_1, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.math.Vector
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:762)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableName.getClass(WritableName.java:71)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.getValueClass(SequenceFile.java:1613)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.init(SequenceFile.java:1555)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1428)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1417)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1412)
at   org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileRecordReader.initialize(SequenceFileRecordReader.java:50)
at    org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.initialize(MapTask.java:418)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:620)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:305)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:170)

11/10/16 21:06:09 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201110161920_0008_m_000000_2,     Status : FAILED
    Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.math.Vector
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:247)
at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:762)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.WritableName.getClass(WritableName.java:71)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.getValueClass(SequenceFile.java:1613)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.init(SequenceFile.java:1555)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1428)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1417)
at org.apache.hadoop.io.SequenceFile$Reader.<init>(SequenceFile.java:1412)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.SequenceFileRecordReader.initialize(SequenceFileRecordReader.java:50)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask$NewTrackingRecordReader.initialize(MapTask.java:418)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:620)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:305)
at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:170)

11/10/16 21:06:18 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201110161920_0008
11/10/16 21:06:18 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 3
11/10/16 21:06:18 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
11/10/16 21:06:18 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Launched map tasks=4
11/10/16 21:06:18 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Data-local map tasks=4
11/10/16 21:06:18 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Failed map tasks=1
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InterruptedException: K-Means Iteration failed processing output/clusters-0/part-randomSeed
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.runIteration(KMeansDriver.java:363)
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.buildClustersMR(KMeansDriver.java:310)
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.buildClusters(KMeansDriver.java:237)
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.kmeans.KMeansDriver.run(KMeansDriver.java:152)
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.syntheticcontrol.kmeans.Job.run(Job.java:149)
at org.apache.mahout.clustering.syntheticcontrol.kmeans.Job.main(Job.java:60)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver$ProgramDescription.invoke(ProgramDriver.java:68)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.ProgramDriver.driver(ProgramDriver.java:139)
at org.apache.mahout.driver.MahoutDriver.main(MahoutDriver.java:187)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

Can somebody please tell me how to rectify this . This would really mean a lot.
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means you did not supply all of the classes need to run your job to Hadoop. The JAR file that you send it has to package up all dependencies, including all Mahout classes from its core and math modules. Fortunately, Mahout does this for you. See the "job" file it creates when you build it, which appears in `target/`.

Comment: Do i look in examples/target directory or the newly generated target directory ?

Comment: They say Mahout's mahout-examples-$MAHOUT_VERSION.job does the actual clustering task and so it needs to be created. Can you please tell me how to create this ? I'm really grateful for your help . I think i went wrong in this step.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the **`org.apache.mahout.math`** package:

```
Error: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.mahout.math.Vector
```